# update. Help me, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here, is a code that updates the data in the fees column that corresponds to the Student ID entered by the student. There are no errors in the code, but the program doesn't seem to update the value in the database.

```
  Private Sub dbupdate()
        'Create a connection object.
        myConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
              & "uid=root;" _
              & "pwd=password;" _
              & "database=dummystudents"

        Try
            'open the connection
            Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
            conn.Open()

            'create a command object.
            sql = "UPDATE students SET fees = '" & txtBalance.Text & "'WHERE idstudents = '" & txtStudentID.Text
            command = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Close connection
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a debugger? I mean *really using* a debugger? Put a breakpoint after you build the sql and inspect the actual sql. Does it look correct?

```sql
UPDATE students SET fees = 'txtBalanceText'WHERE idstudents = 'txtStudentIDText
```

You may notice it's missing a closing single quote after student id. Also, I wonder what types `fees` and `idstudents` are in your database. If they are numeric, which they should be, then you don't use single quotes at all. If they are text then you do need the quotes. Fix the quotes. You can add another single quote like this

```vb
sql = "UPDATE students SET fees = '" & txtBalance.Text & "' WHERE idstudents = '" & txtStudentID.Text & "'"
```

The above code will just fix the missing quote.

However, [you should parameterize your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542542/832052), and not just use textboxes directly. Your code is prone to sql injection, which you should take seriously. In essence, this code is vulnerable to someone putting their own subquery inside the textbox, like this

[image]

Here is how you can improve your code. For one, use `Using` blocks to create and dispose the connection and command. These objects may have unmanaged memory behind the scenes and you should always either call `obj.Dispose()` or let the `Using` block handle it automatically. Also, this sample adds your parameters which effectively avoids the aforementioned sql injection risk

```vb
Dim myConnectionString = "server=localhost;" &
    "uid=root;" &
    "pwd=password;" &
    "database=dummystudents"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql = "UPDATE students SET fees = @fees WHERE idstudents = @studentID"
    Using com As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fees", txtBalance.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", txtStudentID.Text)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Depending on the field types, adding the parameters will either include or exclude the single quotes so you don't need to worry about that anymore - an added bonus.

Comment: Thanks, @djv for the help and advice. But I still don't seem to understand parameterization and how to go about it

Comment: @KB21 check the link I provided, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I did, but I still don't. Can you create an instance and explain it line by line

Comment: @KB21 I added an example

Comment: @djv Have you seen [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), or [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And you should really link to [the source of the cartoon](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton [Doesn't apply to MySQL](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/)

Comment: @Jimi Ooh, I keep forgetting about that one, and I am not competent to comment on the decisions made in making it work that way.